# Changing a Image Source at runtime does not display the image

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, binding, ivalueconverter, imagesource

I am trying to display an Image within a ListBox.ItemTemplate depending on its binding value, the binding value is the status of an object (pending, retrieved, posted, complete or errored), here is the XAML for the Image element.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StatusImageConverter x:Key="StatusImage" />
</Window.Resources>

<Image Source="{Binding Path=Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusImage}}" />
```

I have added 2 images (Badge_tick, Badge_cross) to the Project resource and use the IValueConverter interface to convert the status to an Image which will be displayed in the template, here is the Converter class

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(PreTripItem.PreTripItemStatus), typeof(Bitmap))]
public class StatusImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        PreTripItem.PreTripItemStatus status = (PreTripItem.PreTripItemStatus)value;

        switch (status)
        {
            case PreTripItem.PreTripItemStatus.Complete:
                return new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Badge_tick);
            case PreTripItem.PreTripItemStatus.Error:
                return new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Badge_cross);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();  //Does not need to be converted back
    }
}
```

This builds/compiles fine and runs but when the status changes the image is not displayed within the TemplateItem. I am using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface within my classes so the interface knows when the property is changed automatically so I know straight away that is not the problem :)

I have trawled through the university of google and seen lot of posts with the same problem in principle but not come accross a solution when using the converter interface and project resources.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

All my other IValueConverter classes are working perfectly, just not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning a *BitmapSource* type inplace of *Bitmap*

Bits to change:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(PreTripItem.PreTripItemStatus), typeof(BitmapSource))]
```

and return a BitmapImage as in:

```
return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/Image1.png"));
```

Comment: This has worked, thank you. Only downside to your answer I now have to learn Uri's lol

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem may be in your use of the standard Bitmap class, which is not an ImageSource derived type.

You need to use an ImageSource type:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx

See this if you don't know about pack URIs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Comment: Thank you, the MSN article on Pack Uri's was very helpful